# Magento Wordpress Multisite - Wrong Dashboard

Tags: magento-enterprise, multistore, dashboard, wordpress

I am using the Fishpig WordPress Integration with WP Multisite, and I cannot get to the subsites Dashboard, only the main one.

`magento/wordpress/wp-config.php` (partial)

```
...
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'mydomain.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/news/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);

define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/');
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '');
define('COOKIEPATH', '');
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '');
...
```

`magento/wordpress/.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a third party module

Comment: Yes, however it is a fairly commonly used module. I've seen others ask questions about this module here before, and the developer of the extension frequents these boards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem isn't related to the [Magento WordPress Integration](http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/wordpress-integration/) extension but is a pure WP problem. From my experience, this occurs for 1 of 2 reasons:

1) Your .htaccess file does not contain the correct redirects or you are using a server (Nginx) that does not read .htaccess files.

2) The URL's for either your WP Network or sub-sites are not set correctly and uniformly across the installation.

Feel free to contact me directly at http://fishpig.co.uk/contact-us/ and I can help you debug this.